# Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, econnrefused

I working with node.js by expressjs 
 I try to store an account to session. So, i try to test to use session with code in [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)

```
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat", store: new RedisStore }));
```

but I got error `Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED`. 
 Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: Is Redis running? Can you connect to it by other means e.g. redis-cli?

Comment: Thank u, because redis server not running. I install redis-server follow [this tutorial](https://redistogo.com/documentation/introduction_to_redis)

Comment: You should instal Redis server on your machine and rune it. I donot know why the author doesn't mentioned this important thing in the manual!

Comment: How do I add redis-server for my node Heroku app? I also have same error.

Answer (score 266):

After you install redis, type from terminal:

```
redis-server
```

and you'll have redis running

Comment: For me, I should specify the conf, so I type >> (sudo) redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

Comment: Thank you. Stupid how in the tutorial they never mentioned how to start the redis server!

Comment: `redis-server --daemonize yes` to run in background

Comment: @morteza-ziyae How do I stop redis server in the background?

Answer (score 78):

I solve this problem in next way:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

then run command to confirm that everything ok:

```
sudo service redis-server status
```

And the output will be: `redis-server is running` - that means that the problem is solved.

Comment: that error fixed but now new error show i.e, "Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command"

Comment: Thanks! this resolved the issue, just a small note on Linux/WSL environments after installing re-run the command `redis-server` or prefix it by sudo if needed. If all goes well, you will see redis-server cli message. also can be verified by `sudo service redis-server status` as suggested by @author.

Answer (score 52):

Install redis on your system first -

```
brew install redis
```

then start the redis server -

```
redis-server
```

Comment: brew services start redis is better

Answer (score 23):

I'm on windows, and had to install Redis from [here](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads) and then run `redis-server.exe`.

From the top of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038128/nodejs-using-redis-connect-redis-with-express).

Answer (score 21):

For those of you who are using docker with docker-compose and Typescript my solution was

```js
import { RedisClient } from 'redis';

 const pubClient = new RedisClient({ url: 'redis://redis:6379' });
```

to

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const pubClient = createClient({ url: 'redis://redis:6379' });
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  main:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: npm run start:dev
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0.2-focal
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.5-alpine

volumes:
  mongo-data:
```

Comment: thank you it fixed my issue, don't know why it is not taking port and host as input

Answer (score 15):

> Simple solution:

**only hit below commend once and restart your server again**

```
redis-server
```

Answer (score 6):

**Using Windows 10?**
Go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install

Then run...

```
    $ wget https://github.com/antirez/redis/archive/5.0.5.tar.gz <- change this to whatever Redis version you want (https://github.com/antirez/redis/releases)
    $ tar xzf redis-5.0.5.tar.gz
    $ cd redis-5.0.5
    $ make
```

Answer (score 5):

for Windows users, you can use chocolatey to install Redis

```
choco install redis-64
```

then run server from

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64\redis-server.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

I also have the same problem, first I tried to restart redis-server by `sudo service restart` but the problem still remained. Then I removed `redis-server` by `sudo apt-get purge redis-server` and install it again by `sudo apt-get install redis-server` and then the redis was working again. It also worth to have a look at redis log which located in here `/var/log/redis/redis-server.log`

Answer (score 3):

I used ubuntu 12.04
I solved that problem by installing redis-server

[redis-server installation for ubuntu 12.04](https://library.linode.com/databases/redis/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin)

some configuration will new root permission
Also listed manuals for other OS

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me I had this issue on Ubuntu 18.x, but my problem was that my redis-server was running on 127.0.0.1 but I found out I needed to run it on my IP address xxx.xx.xx.xx

I went into my Ubuntu machine and did the following.

`cd /etc/redis/`

`sudo vim redis.conf`

Then I edited this part.

```
################################## NETWORK #####################################

# By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis listens
# for connections from all the network interfaces available on the server.
# It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
# the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or more IP addresses.
#
# Examples:
#
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
#
# ~~~ WARNING ~~~ If the computer running Redis is directly exposed to the
# internet, binding to all the interfaces is dangerous and will expose the
# instance to everybody on the internet. So by default we uncomment the
# following bind directive, that will force Redis to listen only into
# the IPv4 loopback interface address (this means Redis will be able to
# accept connections only from clients running into the same computer it
# is running).le to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
#
# IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT YOUR INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO ALL THE INTERFACES
# JUST COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE.
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1 10.0.0.1
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1 # <<-------- change this to what your iP address is something like (bind 192.168.2.2)
```

Save that, and then restart redis-server.

`sudo service redis-server restart` or simply run `redis-server`

Answer (score 1):

For windows platform, You must check if `redis-server` is running on given ip:port. you can find redis configuration at installation directory `/conf/redis.conf`. by default client accept `127.0.0.1:6379`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on MBP , and install [redis](http://redis.io/download) detail my problem was resolved .Fixed the 
Download, extract and compile Redis with:

```
$ wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.2.tar.gz

$ tar xzf redis-3.0.2.tar.gz

$ cd redis-3.0.2

$ make
```

The binaries that are now compiled are available in the src directory.

Run Redis with:

```
$ src/redis-server
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you installed redis by source code.If that you need locate to redis-source-code-path/utils and run `sudo install_server.sh` command.
After that, make sure redis-server has been running as a service for your system
`sudo service redis-server status`

PS: based on Debian/Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

In case of ubuntu, the error is due to redis-server not being set up.
Install the redis-server again and then check for the status.

If there is no error, then a message like this would be displayed :-

● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-01-17 20:07:27 IST; 16s ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
 Main PID: 4327 (redis-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─4327 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Answer (score 1):

You have to install redis server first;

You can install redis server on mac by following step -

```
  $ curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
  $ tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz
  $ cd redis-stable
  $ make
  $ make test
  $ sudo make install
  $ redis-server
```

Good luck.

Comment: Be aware: This will take some time to run. If you have a dependency manager (brew or other) this will save you time.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to redis is failing. Try restarting your redis server, then starting up your client again by running these 3 commands:

```
sudo service redis-server restart
redis-server
redis-cli
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Comment: i got this error in ubuntu...solve with this commands..now it's working fine .....

Answer (score 0):

For Windows I solved this by...

using...

```
let redisClient = createClient({
  legacyMode: true ,
  url: 'redis://redis:6379',
});
```

Its for redis version > 4.0
You can refer to the image below.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

If your project runs on windows,

1. You must setup and run redis-server on your windows.
2. Run 'npm i redis' in your project
   It will  work correctly

Comment: Hi, please note, original question was 11 years ago. But, why Windows? There is no such detail  in the question…

Comment: Hi, I know that original question was 11 years ago, but in my  project I got this error and solved with this commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you run redis in docker you must set port:

[image]

Answer (score -7):

Try upgrading your node to latest version.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

version 0.4 may not work properly.