# Redis unable to connect with env port

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm trying to create a Redis client. However whenever I do:

```
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.PORT || 6379;

const client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT);
```

I get `AbortError: Ready check failed: Fatal error encountered. Command aborted. It might have been processed.`

However if I do:

```
const REDIS_PORT = 6379;
    
const client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT);
```

It connects properly. Why do I get this error when I put `process.env.PORT`?

Comment: are you using node.js ?

Comment: Yes I am using nodejs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs - Using redis, connect-redis with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038128/nodejs-using-redis-connect-redis-with-express)

Comment: you did not say either it's a standalone or a cluster? which client are you exactly using? https://redis.io/clients#nodejs

Comment: It's a standalone and i'm using node_redis. Everything else works except when I include process.env.PORT, any reasons?

Comment: So `process.env.PORT || 6379 ` means: whatever is in the environment variable PORT, or 6379 if there's nothing there. So you pass that to `app.listen`, or to `app.set('port', ...)`, and that makes your server able to accept a "what port to listen on" parameter from the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked back on this question a few years later and it's really obvious what the problem was.

When I was running my nodejs app, I had assigned PORT to something in my `.env` which I was then passing into the Redis client. However because Redis listens on port 6379 by default, the client would never connect as there is no redis server running on `PORT`. As a result, I got `AbortError: Ready check failed: Fatal error encountered. Command aborted. It might have been processed.`

So all you have to do is make sure redis is running on whatever `process.env.PORT` is or just keep it on port 6379