# Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

```
LT027296-Mac:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mongo               latest              394204d45d87        3 weeks ago         410MB
redis               latest              a55fbf438dfd        4 weeks ago         95MB
nginx               latest              2bcb04bdb83f        4 weeks ago         109MB
bitnami/mysql       latest              c5c056b8435c        3 months ago        287MB
LT027296-Mac:~$ docker run --name some-redis -d redis
15e126e26ea452b2b8c2933c549a15d74bb49aece1fe8b5e4b746e67bced6c20
LTB0207296-Mac:~ b0207296$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
15e126e26ea4        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   6379/tcp            some-redis
LT027296-Mac:~$
```

Hi 
I am learning redis  tutorial from below link 
https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/introduction-to-caching-redis-node-js-e477eb969eab

I do the following steps

1. Download redis image from docker
2. then run container (as shown above)
3. Then I run my code

```
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const redis = require('redis')

// create express application instance
const app = express()

// create and connect redis client to local instance.
const client = redis.createClient()

// echo redis errors to the console
client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Error " + err)
});

// get photos list
app.get('/photos', (req, res) => {
  // key to store results in Redis store
  const photosRedisKey = 'user:photos';

  // Try fetching the result from Redis first in case we have it cached
  return client.get(photosRedisKey, (err, photos) => {

    // If that key exists in Redis store
    if (photos) {

      return res.json({ source: 'cache', data: JSON.parse(photos) })

    } else { // Key does not exist in Redis store

      // Fetch directly from remote api
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(photos => {

        // Save the  API response in Redis store,  data expire time in 3600 seconds, it means one hour
        client.setex(photosRedisKey, 3600, JSON.stringify(photos))

        // Send JSON response to client
        return res.json({ source: 'api', data: photos })

      })
        .catch(error => {
        // log error message
        console.log(error)
        // send error to the client
        return res.json(error.toString())
      })
    }
  });
});

// start express server at 3000 port
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port: ', 3000)
});
```

I am getting this error

> Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: I have a hunch that you haven't started your redis server. Can you try starting the redis server first? `redis-server` in your command line and then run your node project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754304/redis-connection-to-127-0-0-16379-failed-connect-econnrefused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While running the docker image you've to publish the port as well.

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis -p 6379:6379
```

This will map `docker`'s port to `host` port

Optionally you can also pass the host as well:

```
-p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001
```

Read more about publish [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111060/what-is-the-difference-between-expose-and-publish-in-docker)